How can I execute multiple update statements for a list of id's in PostgresSQL all at once?
I have 3 UPDATE statements (that update more than one column) that I would like to execute against a list of id's without having to run the 3 update statements one by one against each id.
Here are the 3 update statements I need to run against a bunch of ids:
-- store ContractDate value in temp col
update tval set temp_col = (select val from tval where id = 402280209 and fid = 3782) where id = 402280209 and fid = 3782


-- Replace ContractDate with maturityDate
update tval set val= (select val from tval where fid = 3771 and id = 402280209) where fid = 3782 and id = 402280209


-- set MaturityDate to ContactDate
update tval set val = (select temp_col from tval where id = 402280209 and fid = 3782) where id = 402280209 and fid = 3771

I have a list of id's that I need to run the above 3 update statement against. Is it possible to run the above as a batch (i.e. in one query)?
For reference my tval table looks something like this:
    id       fid              ts                      val                 temp_col
402280209   3765    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   2023-12-19 00:00:00.000   
402280209   3771    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   2023-09-20 00:00:00.000   <---- I would like to swap this value
402280209   3782    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   2023-12-19 00:00:00.000   <----- with this value

What I am trying to avoid is running the above manually for each id.
So my desired result is:
    id       fid              ts                      val                 temp_col
402280209   3765    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   2023-12-19 00:00:00.000   
402280209   3771    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   2023-12-19 00:00:00.000   
402280209   3782    2021-09-20 00:00:00.000   2023-09-20 00:00:00.000   


It seems from later clarification that you want to swap values in two different rows not columns. That is more complex. One option is to use a (constructed?) table to join both source and target rows. As long as both directions are present in this join table then it will swap them correctly.
update tval
set val = source.val
from (values
    (3771, 3782),
    (3782, 3771)
) v(fidTarget, fidSource)
join tval source
  on source.fid = v.fidSource
where tval.id = 402280209
  and v.fidTarget = tval.fid
  and source.id = tval.id;

db<>fiddle

Thanks for the solution @charlieface.
One small issue - I am trying to 'do the swap' of the two values in the val column, and not create two extra columns.
I have added the desired result to my question

OK see new edits.

You are a magician, it worked! Thank you sir. I'll try and dissect each part to understand it.

You can do
update tval
set temp_col = val,
    val= (select val from tval where fid = 3771 and id = 402280209)
where fid = 3782 and id = 402280209

that is, use the set keyword and then comma-separate what you actually want to set.
Your algorithm seems to indicate that you want to store a value in a temporary column and then override your value and then copy back your temporary column. I would do the latest update in a separate query.
EDIT
Trying to update field of the first record and vice versa seems to work according to this example:
create table tbl(id int, val int);

insert into tbl(id, val)
values(1, 1),
      (2, 2);

update tbl
set val = t2.val
from tbl t2
where tbl.id in (1, 2) and t2.id in (1, 2) and tbl.id <> t2.id;

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nsY2HBX1Wy8f61dAL7ZtM7/1

Your dbfiddle links to a MySQL test. AFAIK PostgreSQL does not implement joins in the UPDATE statement (it's not standard SQL, it's a MySQL extension).

@BillKarwin thanks, Bill for pointing that out, I was absent-minded during the initial answer. Adjusted the fiddle to use PostgreSQL.

Thanks for the answer @Lajos, when I execute the query it throws an error around the 3782  - is that in the right place?

If I remove the 3782 then the query sets the two values as the same thing, which is not quite what I was after.

@user21641220 indeed, that was a typo on my part. Thanks for pointing it out.

It looks to me that your true goal is to swap val values for the fids 3771 and 3782.  If that is so, you don't need temp_col at all.
If you are on PostgreSQL ver 15 or later, you can use the MERGE sql statement.  Otherwise, you can do the same thing with UPDATE...FROM.  Major idea #1 is to design a query that contains the table keys and values you desire.  Major idea #2 is to add a defensive mechanism in case one of the fid records does not exist.  Your current triple update would mess up badly if one row were missing.
The Merge statement would be:
Merge into tval u Using (
    Select id, Case When fid=3771 Then 3782 Else 3771 End as fid
      , val, count(*) Over () as nbr
    From tval
    Where id=402280209 and fid in (3771,3782)
) v On u.id=v.id and u.fid=v.fid and v.nbr=2
When Matched then Update Set val=v.val

The older Update syntax would be
Update tval u From ( <same query as above> ) v
    Where <same criteria as above>
Set val=v.val


When I run the query it throws a syntax error because ofMerge. I am using postgres SQL
